# Have Information Theoretic results been used in other branches of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, information-theory

consider this a soft-question.
Information Theory is fairly young branch of mathematics (60 years).

I am interested in question,  whether there have been any information theoretic results that had impact on other seemingly 'unrelated' branches of mathematics?

Looking forward to hearing you thoughts.

Comment: There is a standard proof that no algorithm for comparison-based sorting can achieve better than $O(n\log n)$ worst-case performance that is purely information-theoretic.

Comment: As far as I remember the proof simply finds the depth of the decision tree. Wouldn't this be more graph theory or combinatorics?

Comment: The proof is roughly: There are $n!$ possible orders, which by Stirling's approximation is close to $(n/e)^n$. To distinguish between them requires  $\log \bigl((n/e)^n\bigr)$ bits of information, which is $n\log n$. Each comparison produces only 1 bit of information, so $n\log n$ comparisons are required.

Comment: In this case I agree. Could you put it as an answer. I really want this question to start going.

Comment: Entropy is pretty important for large deviations theory.

Comment: @Alex R. Is there a specific result you have in mind?

Comment: Specifically, the rate function for large deviations is connected to entropy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory#Large_deviations_and_entropy

Comment: @AlexR you should consider putting your comment as answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a theorem that no comparison sorting algorithm can have a worst-case running time better than $O(n\log n)$, and this limit is often referred to as an *information-theoretic* limit on the running time. (For example, see Leiserson et al. *Introduction to Algorithms* (2001) pp. 181 and preceding, or Knuth *The Art of Computer Programming* **3** (1998) pp. 182–183 “Relation (1) is often called the *information-theoretic lower bound*…”.)

This is because there are $n!$ possible orders for a list of  $n$ items, and therefore  $\lceil \log_2 n!\rceil$ bits are required to specify one of these orders.  By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), this is  $O(n\log n)$ bits.

But a comparison of two elements  produces only one bit of information about the permutation, so $O(n\log n)$ comparisons are required to identify which permutation is given.

The paper [“The information theoretic bound for problems on ordered sets and graphs”](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-5315-4_4) (Michael Saks, 1985) says “This is an example of an information theoretic bound (ITB) for a combinatorial decision problem, one of the few general techniques known for obtaining lower bounds on the computation complexity of a problem. … This paper is a survey of a number of computational problems involving ordered sets andgraphis in which the ITB can be applied.”