# A lower bound on sorting algorithms

Tags: optimization, proof-verification, algorithms, sorting

I think I have a proof that $n\ln n$ is optimal in the sense that is it a lower bound for sorting algorithms.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for a list.

It must be greater than $n$ as this is too linear, and the $\ln$ factor comes from the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which represents the reductions by dividing the sort list.

Has this already been proved (or disproved)?

Comment: Optimal can mean many things, average, worst case, etc. But it is well know that the complexity is bounded by $n \ln n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $n$ elements there are $n!$ possible orderings. Each comparison you make between two elements reduces the space of possible elements by a half. In order to uniquely determine which ordering we are in, we have to perform enough comparisons to cover all possible orderings.

All orderings can be represented in $\log_2 n!$ bits, which is to say we need $O(\log_2 n!)$ comparisons. Using [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), $\log_2(n!) \approx \frac1{\ln 2}(n \ln n - n + O(\ln n))$. Asymptotically, $O(\log_2 n!) = O(n \log n)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks. I mean, the constant still doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

It's well known that comparison sorts require $n \log n$ operations in the worst case to sort $n$ things. You can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list) for a proof or these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf) by Avirm Blum.

However, if you don't use a comparison-based sort (e.g. bucket or radix sort), you can break the $n \log n$ barrier.

Comment: Obviously, we have upper bounds on the same order (heap/merge/etc). And the average case. Under appropriate models of computation, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is known as the *information-theoretic upper bound* for sorting and has been known since the 1960s. However, it applies only to comparison sorts, where individual elements are compared pairwise.  ([Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is a commonly-cited counterexample in this context.)  Wikipedia has a discussion in [their article on comparison sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list).

My discussion in [Have Information Theoretic results been used in other branches of mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112365/25554) has some more details and references to the literature.